# how to remove side navigation and top header area from all pages in SharePoint using SPFx

Tags: spfx

I'm trying to remove side navigation and top header area from SharePoint but the result is reflecting only on homepage.

How can I remove it from all pages?
Is there any way to remove this with SPFx extension with out using old css technique

```
#sideNavBox,#titleAreaRow
{
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing it from all pages, you will need to include this CSS code in custom MasterPage and use that MasterPage for your site.

Comment: I am using SPFx and not changing  master page. Is there any way in SPFx?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use an SPFx Application Customizer and reference the JS/CSS you want to remove.

Chris O’Brien has written an excellent post on this. http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html?m=1

Comment: I want to remove top header area and side navigation.Adding placeholder is just creating top and bottom zones but it does not change existing CSS.Can you provide any example where site layout is changed by extension except adding header and footer zone.